# Arch model in python is returning "Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'double' but got 'float'"

Tags: python, time-series, arch, fgarch

I am trying to develop a Volatility model for some stock indexes using python and the arch model.
I am comparing the solution developed by this third party library with some proprietary code I have.
Unofrtunately, when using the fit method on the ARCH model, it breaks and raises the following error.

ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'double' but got 'float'

I am not sure what to do.

I want to fit a garch model to see if my calculations do match the code by 3rd party library.

```
import yfinance as yf
from arch import arch_model
import numpy as np

SPX = yf.download('^GSPC', start = '2005-01-01', interval = '1d')
SPX['log_returns'] = np.log(SPX['Adj Close']) - np.log(SPX['Adj Close'].shift(1))
arch_mSPX = arch_model(SPX['log_returns'][1:] * 100, mean = 'Zero', vol = 'GARCH')
arch_mSPX = arch_mSPX.fit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Is SPX a dataframe? Perhaps try to cast your data explicitly as a double:

```
SPX = yf.download('^GSPC', start = '2005-01-01', interval = '1d')
SPX = SPX.astype('double')
SPX['log_returns'] = np.log(SPX['Adj Close']) - np.log(SPX['Adj Close'].shift(1))
arch_mSPX = arch_model(SPX['log_returns'][1:] * 100, mean = 'Zero', vol = 'GARCH')
arch_mSPX = arch_mSPX.fit()
```

EDIT:
He simply uninstalled arch 6.2.0 and reinstalled arch 6.1.0, and the issue was resolved

Comment: Tried casting using the code provided but it seems that the type of SPX is still float64, as I called SPC.iloc[:,0].dtype and the result was float64

Comment: Have you check for na values?

Comment: actually the first element is a 'na' but i input only the second value onwards in the function above

Comment: Okay, sorry for redundancy, but you've verified there's none elsewhere?

Comment: Yeah, I tried using a custom list of values generated using np.random.randn and still the error persists, so it's not my data

Comment: I uninstalled arch 6.2.0 and installed the older version 6.1.0 and now it runs successfully

Comment: Sweet! Good to hear, I was kinda at a loss for what to do. I'll edit my answer, or you can add yours, in case someone else stumbled across this.